# Making a list out of ... function arguments

Tags: r

Here's a puzzle I just ran across:

```
x <- data.frame(a="hi",b="lo")
y <- data.frame(a="hi",b="lo")

getCommonNames <- function(...) {
  l <- list(...)
  sapply( l, names )
}
```

vs.

```
getCommonNames2 <- function(...) {
  sapply( list(...), names )
}


> getCommonNames2(x,y)
Error in lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : 
  argument "X" is missing, with no default
> getCommonNames(x,y)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "a" 
[2,] "b"  "b"
```

Why does `list(...)` properly coerce its contents to a list when stored to something (or used as a return value), but not when it is used in a expression without storing it first?

This seems like a triviality, but it sort of broke my mental model of R parsing, in which everything gets resolved then stored or passed along to the next argument.  I've learned not to ignore such moments, as re-building my mental model to take the new information into account often results in a deeper understanding of things.

So...what's going on here?

Comment: I do not get the error you are getting:
`> getCommonNames2(x,y)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "a" 
[2,] "b"  "b"` (Sorry, can't get multi-line output showing up correctly).

Comment: I checked on another computer and also can't replicate there.  So I assume it's a bug as has been pointed out.  Voting to close as too localized.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a bug in your version of R or some missmatch in your current environment.

My version does not reproduce the same problem, it just goes as expected.

```
> x <- data.frame(a="hi",b="lo")
> y <- data.frame(a="hi",b="lo")
> 
> getCommonNames <- function(...) {
+   l <- list(...)
+   sapply( l, names )
+ }
> 
> 
> getCommonNames2 <- function(...) {
+   sapply( list(...), names )
+ }
> 
> getCommonNames2(x,y)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "a" 
[2,] "b"  "b" 
> getCommonNames(x,y)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "a" 
[2,] "b"  "b" 


version.string R version 2.14.0 (2011-10-31)
```

Comment: Ditto: R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)